# mapping in react using props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have fetched groups from my API and I can see they come through to the UI and the props, but somehow displaying the name of the groups is not happening.

This is how i mapped it:

```
<List>
    {this.props.groups && this.props.groups.map((g) =>
    <ListItem key={g.Id} primaryText={g.Name} onClick={this.handleClickItem(g)} />) }

    {(!this.props.groups || this.props.groups.length === 0) && "No groups found."}
</List>
```

[redux devtools showing the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPziO.png)
[showing the props hold the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjflT.png)

Answer (score 0):

I saw lower case of 'name' property:
It should 'g.name' not 'g.Name'

Comment: I tried that actually without any luck.
When I console.log the entire object 'g' then it comes through alright, but when I try to console.log(g.Name) it says undefined :/

Comment: He's saying that `g` doesn't have a property `Name`, which is why you're getting undefined.  It's lowercase.  Try logging `g.name`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at output of your props the keys in the groups object are lowercase. `g.name` not `g.Name`, the error you are receiving is because of case sensitivity. Also onClick requires you to pass a function, without the arrow function the handleClickItem function would be called when React renders the component.

Your ListItem component should be:

```
<ListItem 
  key={g.id}
  primaryText={g.name}
  onClick={ () => this.handleClickItem(g) } 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are mapping an array of arrays that is why you can't access the elements by key.

Answer (score 0):

It was a matter of case sensitivity beacuse I had imported the type and not the model so g.name is now available and working.